# .NET serialization of Array to XML. How to set an alias for array type?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, arrays, serialization

I'm trying to figure out serialization of .net arrays to XML. Here's a piece of code that I've come up with:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public class Person 
        {
            public string Firstname { get; set; }
            public string Lastname { get; set; }
            public uint Age { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main ()
        {
            Person[] p = 
            {
                new Person{Age = 20, Firstname = "Michael", Lastname = "Jackson"},
                new Person{Age = 21, Firstname = "Bill", Lastname = "Gates"},
                new Person{Age = 22, Firstname = "Steve", Lastname = "Jobs"}
            };

            SerializeObject<Person[]>(p);
        }

        static void SerializeObject<T>(T obj) where T : class
        {
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".xml";
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName)) 
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                ser.Serialize(fs, obj, ns);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's an XML content that this example writes down to the XML file:

```
<ArrayOfPerson>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Michael</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jackson</Lastname>
    <Age>20</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Bill</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Gates</Lastname>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Steve</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jobs</Lastname>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

But this is not really what I want. I would like it to look like this:

```
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Michael</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jackson</Lastname>
    <Age>20</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Bill</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Gates</Lastname>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Steve</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jobs</Lastname>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

How could I get it working this way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make some small changes to your code, in addition to the suggestions already provided.

First the SerializeObject generic method needs to be redeclared thus:

```
// important: declare the input parameter to be an **array** of T, not T.
static void SerializeObject<T>(T[] obj) where T : class
{
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".xml";
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        // override default root node name.  based on your question, 
        // i'm just going to append an "s" to the base type 
        // (e.g., Person becomes Persons)
        var rootName = typeof(T).Name + "s";
        XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute(rootName);

        // add the attribute to the serializer constructor...
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), root);

        ser.Serialize(fs, obj, ns);
    }
}
```

Secondly, in the Main() method, replace `SerializeObject<Person[]>(p)` with `SerializeObject<Person>(p)`.  Thus your Main() method will look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person[] p = 
    {
        new Person{Age = 20, Firstname = "Michael", Lastname = "Jackson"},
        new Person{Age = 21, Firstname = "Bill", Lastname = "Gates"},
        new Person{Age = 22, Firstname = "Steve", Lastname = "Jobs"}
    };

    SerializeObject<Person>(p);
}
```

The resulting XML will look like this:

```
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Michael</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jackson</Lastname>
    <Age>20</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Bill</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Gates</Lastname>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Firstname>Steve</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jobs</Lastname>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

To override the `<Person>` element name to something else, set the `XmlType` attribute on the class, like so:

```
[XmlType("personEntry")]
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public uint Age { get; set; }
}
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
<Persons>
  <personEntry>
    <Firstname>Michael</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jackson</Lastname>
    <Age>20</Age>
  </personEntry>
  <personEntry>
    <Firstname>Bill</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Gates</Lastname>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </personEntry>
  <personEntry>
    <Firstname>Steve</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Jobs</Lastname>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </personEntry>
</Persons>
```

Comment: Nice stuff! Thank you very much!

Comment: Considering this code, could I control name of array child nodes somehow? For example render <personEntry> instead of <Person>...

Answer (score 4):

You need a container class like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an Person collection.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Persons", IsNullable = false)]
    public sealed class Persons
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The person collection.
        /// </summary>
        private Collection<Person> persons;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Persons"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="persons">The person list.</param>
        public Persons(Collection<Person> persons)
        {
            this.persons = persons;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Persons"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="persons">The person array.</param>
        public Persons(Person[] persons)
            : this(new Collection<Person>(persons))
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="Persons"/> class from being created.
        /// </summary>
        private Persons()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copies the collection of Person objects to an array and returns
        /// it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An array of Person objects based on the
        /// collection.</returns>
        public Person[] ToArray()
        {
            Person[] personArray = new Person[this.persons.Count];

            this.persons.CopyTo(personArray, 0);
            return personArray;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the persons.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The persons.</value>
        [XmlElement("Person")]
        public Collection<Person> ThePersons
        {
            get
            {
                return this.persons;
            }

            set
            {
                this.persons = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the length of the persons.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The length of the persons.</value>
        [XmlIgnore]
        public int Length
        {
            get
            {
                return this.persons.Count;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="IEnumerator&lt;Person&gt;"/> that can be used to
        /// iterate through the collection.</returns>
        public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator<Person>)this.persons.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Initialize it with your completed array and return it as per your `Main()` method:

```
    static void Main ()
    {
        Person[] p = 
        {
            new Person{Age = 20, Firstname = "Michael", Lastname = "Jackson"},
            new Person{Age = 21, Firstname = "Bill", Lastname = "Gates"},
            new Person{Age = 22, Firstname = "Steve", Lastname = "Jobs"}
        };

        SerializeObject<Persons>(new Persons(p));

        Person[] p2 = DeserializeObject<Persons>("filename.xml").ToArray();
    }
```

The deserializer method is pretty simple then:

```
    static T DeserializeObject<T>(string fileName) where T : class
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(fs);
        }
    }
```

Option 2 (building on [Nix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256793/nix)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618605/net-serialization-of-array-to-xml-how-to-set-an-alias-for-array-type/3618698#3618698)):

```
    static void SerializeObject<T>(T obj, Type t) where T : class
    {
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".xml";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute(t.Name + "s");
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), root);
            ser.Serialize(fs, obj, ns);
        }
    }
```

can be called as such:

```
        SerializeObject<Person[]>(p, typeof(Person));
```

Comment: +1, good answer (except that you don't need the [Serializable] attribute for XML serialization)

Comment: @Thomas: True fact, thanks.  I did a copy/paste from a project where we have XML serialization and Remoting going on.

Comment: But now the question is... how to get output xml deserialized to Persons object? Any thoughts?

Comment: @the_V: I modded the container class slightly to support deserialization and threw in a quick method to show how to deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a root attribute to your serializer.  See below.

```
 static void SerializeObject<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".xml";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName)) 
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");

            XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute( typeof(T).Name + "s");

            XmlSerializer
              ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]), root);
              ser.Serialize(fs, obj, ns);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you could pass in a func that does the name selecting.
Your code would be

```
 SerializeObject<Person[]>(p, per=>p.GetType().Name);



static void SerializeObject<T>(T obj, Func<T,string> nameSelector) where T : class
{
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".xml";
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute(nameSelector(obj));

        XmlSerializer
          ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]), root);
        ser.Serialize(fs, obj, ns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution now only works for the `Persons` case and not for any other generic `<T>` which is passed into his `SerializeObject` method.

Comment: You could pass in "ArrayName" parameter. Or you could take the type and add an S if you really wanted to.